# Open Java snapshot with JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler

How do I open snapshot taken with jmap with JProfiler? When I try to Open Snapshot I cannot choose the file. Does it have to end with some specific extension?

Answer (score 1):

Give the file an `.hprof` extension, then the default file filter in the file chooser will show it.